# How to execute a file from Python module as __main__ (python -m path.to.file) programatically?

Tags: python, python-module

I have a couple of Python scripts which (due to imports) have to be called with `python`'s `-m` option.

I'd like to make shortcut script for them, which would act like proxy.

For example when user runs command

```
./train.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

the script should do exactly the same thing as

```
python -m some.path.train arg1 arg2 ...
```

would do.

Comment: is `train.py` supposed to figure out `some.path.`?  Because that isn't necessarily even unique...

Comment: @mgilson No, path should be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` switch uses a bit of a hack (like [setting `sys.argv[0]` to `-c`](http://bugs.python.org/issue8202)); don't try to emulate that.

Instead, have both your script and your `__main__.py` use the same function; don't put the functionality all in `__main__.py`.

So in `__main__.py`, do:

```
import sys
from some.path.train import main

main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

and in your `train.py` script do exactly the same:

```
import sys
from some.path.train import main

main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

If you *must* put the code in `__main__.py`, I'd still make it a function you can then import that function for your `train.py` script:

```
from some.path.train.__main__ import main
```

You could use [`setuptools` entry points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) to generate a `train` console script from a function:

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'train = some.path.train:main',
        ],
    }
)
```

or use

```
'train = some.path.train.__main__:main',
```

if you put the function in the `__main__.py` module.

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to emulate `-m` switch without any modifications in the code, but I guess you convinced me to change my mind.

In train.py inside the module and just have some function declarations and then just some instructions (I don't check if module is equal to `__main__` etc. so I wouldn't have to emulate that).

The only thing which forces me to use cumbersome `python -m ...` are imports from upper directories. :|

Maybe you'll would figure out something else.

Comment: @Luke: Trying to emulate the `-m` switch exactly is .. a fools game, and there is just no point. You just need to make sure you have `some` in your module search path when running `training.py`, really.

Comment: I guess when running `./some/path/train.py` I need to have `./some` and `./some/path` in module search path, because `train.py` imports various things from other files under `./**/*`, which import other etc.

Comment: And then comes a question about usability. How do I set the module search path, so the user could call `./some/path/train.py` directly, without additional effort?

Comment: @Luke: no, you *don't* want `./some` and `./some/path` in the path. You want `.` in the search path, so that `import some` finds `./some`.

Comment: @Luke: You can use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to find an absolute path to the directory of the current file. Use that as a basis to augment the `sys.path` module search path.

Comment: I figured out much simpler solution - in `train.py` I put just `from some.path import train` and it works as expected.

Comment: Good, if `train.py` lives next to `some`, then that just works, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution.

In `train.py` I put the line below:

```
from some.path import train
```

It doesn't set `__name__` to `'__main__'` but I never check for that, so it's not a problem in my case.